# Mystery Matrix Subset

Tags: r, matrix

I came across this strange matrix operation the other day and can't figure out what it is doing.
Consider:

```
a<-matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2,c(9,8,7,6))
b<-matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2,c(1,2,1,2))
a[b]
```

Whoa!  How can you even use a matrix to subset another matrix?  Anyway - this is the result

```
 a[b]
 #[1] 9 6
```

I thought maybe b was providing the indexing to reference a (i.e. get 1,1 and then get 2,2.  But if that is what is happening the rules get thrown out of the window when you do this

```
a<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3,c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
b<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3,c(1,2,3,2,2,2,1,1,1))
a[b]
#[1] 9 8 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a mystery. in your second example the indexing matrix `b` is treated as a numeric:

```
as.numeric(b)
#[1] 1 2 3 2 2 2 1 1 1
a[as.numeric(b)]
#[1] 9 8 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

you have to remember that on top of having a two dimensional `ij` (row x column) indexing, matrices also have a one-dimensional one, where each element is assigned a number in sequence, starting with the top-left element and going down the columns.  so `a[1, 1]` is the same as `a[1]` and `a[2, 2]` is the same as `a[5]`. hence `a[b]` gives you `c(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[2],...,a[1])`, which is the same as `c(a[1,1], a[2,1], a[3,1], a[2,1], a[2,1],..., a[1,1])`.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is essentially a numeric vector with a dimension attribute. In R, matrices are stored using "column-major order", meaning that the matrix is filled columnwisely. This implies the following:

```
a <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
> a
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

Since it is also a vector, you will be still be able to access elements of `a` using single indices.

```
> a[1]
#1
> a[2]
#2
> a[3]
#3
```

When you put a variable between the bracket operator, it tries to coerce your variable into an integer vector, such that it becomes a set of indices for the numeric vector `a`.

To understand better, you could try the following:

```
 a<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3,c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
 b<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3,c(1,2,3,2,2,2,1,10,1)) # a[10] = NA
 > a[b]
 # [1]  9  8  7  8  8  8  9 NA  9
```

Since the brackets coerce the matrices into integer vectors, you can even imagine having a `b` matrix with floating values:

```
b<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3,c(1.1,2.1,3.9,2.8,2,2,1,10.5,1))
> a[b]
# [1]  9  8  7  8  8  8  9 NA  9
```

This is because, as said earlier:

```
> as.integer(b) # same as as.integer(c(1.1,2.1,3.9,2.8,2,2,1,10.5,1))
#  1  2  3  2  2  2  1 10  1
```